# Intersect sqlalchemy query objects

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a two sqlalchemy query objects (q1 and q2) - they both belong to the same table and I want to be able to intersect the two queries. Since my database is MySql, q1.intersect(q2) throws sql syntax error. Is there a way to perform intersect MySql queries in sqlalchemy? My research pointed at using subqueries, aliases and left joins but all these solutions are native sql queries. I am looking for a sqlalchemy syntax.

Query:

```
q1 = Model1().query().filter(Model1.description.ilike(%aws%)) 
q2 = Model1().query().filter(Model1.tags.ilike(%cloud%))
```

I want to return `q1.intersect(q2)`

Also, what I have specified here as queries is just one of the cases of a broader set. I have a function which takes in an operator (and/or) and two operands(sql alchemy query objects, q1 and q2) which can be different and complex for different function calls. In this case, I cannot do a nested filter. I need to work with just q1 and q2.

Comment: What is your query?  Intersect may not be the most efficient way to build the query.  What is the exact error you're getting?  Also, sqlalchemy supports subqueries, aliases and left joins.

Comment: query1 = Model1().query().filter(Model1.description.ilike(%aws%))
query2 = Model1().query().filter(Model1.tags.ilike(%cloud%))

I want to return query1.intersect(query2). But this generates an intersect query which isn't supported in MySql.

Answer (score 0):

For this simple case, you could just use two filters in the same query

```
results = db.query(Model1).filter(
    Model1.description.ilike('%aws'), 
    Model1.tags.ilike('%cloud%')
)
```

This would return the same results as an intersect.

With two separate queries:

```
stmt = q2.subquery()
results = q1.outerjoin(stmt, Model1.id==stmt.c.id).filter(stmt.c.id != None)
```

Comment: What I had specified is just one of the cases of a broader set. I have a function which takes in an operator (and/or) and two operands(sql alchemy query objects, q1 and q2) which can be different and complex for different function calls. In this case, I cannot do a nested filter. I need to work with just q1 and q2.

Comment: I am getting the same error that I used to get for much complex (nested) queries:  

    `dbquery = operand1.outerjoin(subq, eval('{}.uuid'.format(model)) == subq.c.uuid).filter(subq.c.uuid != None)`
      `File "/home/user/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 211, in __getattr__
        raise AttributeError(key)`
    `AttributeError: uuid`
Reason is subq.c.keys() doesn't have 'uuid':
`type(subq.c) = <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.base.ImmutableColumnCollection'>`  
`subq.c.keys() = ['%(139874315762576 anon)s_%(139874315638736 anon)s_<model>_uuid', ...`